# Increasing PostGIS/PostgreSQL memory to avoid Out Of Memory (OOM) error?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

This is a follow-up question to my earlier question about the memory management of some PostGIS/PostgreSQL functions:

[How do PostGIS functions handle buffers and external storage?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/223621/34474)

As suggested by the accepted answer, some of the PostGIS functions (e.g. that rely on GEOS or those in pgrouting)

> do not have any special handling for data sets that are larger than
>   can fit in memory. If you run them on such data sets, you'll just OOM
>   the backend.

So, my question here is that

*If I have a machine with lots of memory, how do I config PostgreSQL/PostGIS so that I don't get OOM error for larger datasets?*

I see [here](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/tuning.html) that there are a few parameters:

```
work_mem, shared_buffers, maintenance_work_mem
```

For example, if I have a `pgrouting` memory taking 100M worth of memory. Which ones in above should be set and what values should I use to **ensure** I don't get an OOM? (assuming no other concurrent use of the database).

Comment: Perhaps the best experts to answer are in https://dba.stackexchange.com/. Or maybe here, if the problem is somehow specific to PostGIS functions.

Comment: Sometimes using too *large* of parameters can cause memory issues, if the buffer is per-process.

Comment: What is your hardware and Operating System specifications for your PostGIS Server?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 11, PostGIS 2.5 under Ubuntu Linux, on different machines with Intel i-5,7, or 9 CPUs

Comment: My two cents: I don't think you can, easily; those settings are actually rather low already by default, and their impact is hard to measure exactly (e.g. the `work_mem` value will be used *per process per node* in the query execution). I'd say it's sth. you have to adjust with the queries you run. Naturally, the general goal should be to limit data to be cached the very minimum, e.g. I doesn't make sense to load 100.000.000 edges into memory to route within a city; rather, limit the graph to the proximity of the input, exclude foot path when routing for cars etc.